# How do spongy substances crack or tear?

Tags: material-science

I read that there is a length (the Griffith critical crack length) beyond which cracks start to become self-propagating. If a crack in a sponge very quickly reaches a hole and stops propagating how do then spongy or porous substances crack or tear?

Comment: There are **a lot** of different spongy and/ or porous materials. IMO, you might need to be more specific. Best of luck with it anyway